# How can I Find specific numbers in a string based on a criteria

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to only return numbers that do not match this criteria. 
an example of the criteria is Apt 2, Department 4 etc

My code below is what I have been trying but it does not work.
the result should be the same as what this outputs **preg_match_all('!\d!', $string, $matches);**

I expect an array with 2 3 4 4 5 4 5 2 3 2 as output. It should exclude the number for Apt 92 and the number in Block 5.

```
$string = "23 St John Apt 92 rer 4, Wellington Country Block 5 No value test 4545 tt 232";
 preg_match_all('!\d(^((?:Apartment|Apt|Block|Department|Lot|Number|Villa)\s*)([0-9]+))!', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: You are totally misunderstanding character classes. What output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match what you need and then use `(*SKIP)(?!)` (or `(*SKIP)(*F)`, or `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`) construct to skip the currently matched index:

```
$re = '/\b(?:Apartment|Apt|Block|Department|Lot|Number|Villa)\s*[0-9]+(*SKIP)(?!)|\d+/'; 
$str = "23 St John Apt 92 rer 4, Wellington Country Block 5 No value test 4545 tt 232"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mQ5sR4/1) and [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/yzz1SK)

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 23
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 4545
    [3] => 232
)
```

Comment: How can I get it to return all the numbers split into single digits

Comment: Just remove the `+` at the end: `$re = '/\b(?:Apartment|Apt|Block|Department|Lot|Number|Villa)\s*[0-9]+(*SKIP)(?!)|\d/';`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $matches);`?